# What happens if I call new on the same object in java twice?

Tags: java, object

So say I have some test java code like this:

```
class A(){
       int a = 0;
       public A{
             a = 1;
       }
 class B(){
       A object = new A(); //Object one
       A object = new A(); //Object two
```

My question is: In class A when I call the new operator on object twice what happens? Does it create a new object A and destroy the old one? Or will it error? Does it just reset the old object?

I have tried this a couple times and don't really understand the output.

Comment: Well, Your code doesnt compile as of now

Comment: `class B(){
       A object = new A(); //Object one
       object = new A(); //Object two`

Comment: You don't. This code does not compile. In any case it is impossible to invoke the `new` operator twice on the same object. What you are doing here is *assigning* a new object to a *reference variable.*

Answer (score 4):

It is a second `A` object.

The first will be garbage collected sooner later.

Note that you can also do

```
new A();
new A();
```

without storing them in a variable. It's perfectly valid, and will be executed.

Also note that

```
A obj1 = new A();
A obj2 = obj1;
```

does *not* copy the object, but it's a reference to the same object. You can also have 0 references, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe this will compile.

But if the question is what happens when I call a constructor twice, the answer is  you get two instances of the class:

```
class A {
    int a = 0;

    public A(int input) {
        a = input;
    }
}

class B {
    A object1 = new A(1); //Object one
    A object2 = new A(2); //Object two
    A object3 = object2;
    //object1 != object2

    public B(){
        A a = new A(3);
        a = new A(4); // a points at the last A defined

        System.out.println(object1.a); //prints 1
        System.out.println(object2.a); //prints 2
        System.out.println(object3.a); //prints 2
        System.out.println(a.a); //prints 4
    }
}
```

Also, if you call `a = new A();` again, the previous a instance is flagged for garbage collection and a is assigned to the new A()

Comment: i think what OP meant wa assiging Object1 to new A object. `A obj1 = new A(); obj1 = new A();`

Comment: @PermGenError It is up to the OP to clarify, not for us to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do here, and your code does not compile. I've created a working example of your code below with comments.

Does this answer your question?

```
public class Main {
    //Test method to instantiate a new B
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B b = new B();
    }
}

class A {
      int a = 0;
        public A() {
         a =1;
        }
}

class B {

    public B() {
        A a = new A();
        //Print first object reference
        System.out.println("First object reference assigned to a: " + a.toString());

        //You cannot instantiate the same field/variable twice.
        // However, you can change the object reference as below
        a = new A();

        //Print second object reference
        System.out.println("Second object reference assigned to a: " + a.toString());

        //As you can see, the object
        // reference points at the new Instance of A when creating a
        // new instance of A and assigning the reference to field a

    }

}
```

If you run this your output will look something like this:

```
First object reference assigned to a: A@750159
Second object reference assigned to a: A@1abab88
```